# Does the httpContext object get instantiated before the entire request is received?

Tags: .net, networking, webforms, httpcontext, latency

.Net 4.5, WinForms web application.   We're using the timeStamp property of the httpContext to log performance metrics. The timeStamp is set during the instantiation of the HttpContext object, and we are using an "end time" that is created in the PostRequestHandlerExecute.  I initially thought that these times would be exclusive of any network latency, but when comparing requests from 2 separate physical locations, one of them is averaging double the time of the other.  The slower location has a history of latency issues.  Because the timings are so drastic in comparison, that tells me either the instantiation of the httpContext , or even the PostRequestHandlerExecute event is adding network time into equation.   I've searched for info on this but did not find anything conclusive.  Thanks

Edit:  The requests that doubled in duration were POSTS of heavy aspx pages with embedded session state.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb470252%28v=vs.140%29.aspx

Comment: Is this what you're referring to? "After the application domain has been created and the HostingEnvironment object has been instantiated, application objects such as HttpContext, HttpRequest, and HttpResponse are created and initialized."  That doesn't provide the insight I need.  Thanks for the link though.